# Which is the full url for file types' icons in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm building a webpart in Visual Studio 2010 and I would like to show the files' icons next to its name. I thought that myFile.IconUrl would return the full url, but I only get its filename along with its extension.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most file type icons are kept in the 14 hive under /_layouts/images.

ie: /_layouts/images/ICBMP.GIF